# assume I write a record into cassandra cluster, and read it immediatelly. How can cassandra guarantee what I read is the latest result I just wrote?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

assume I write a record into cassandra cluster, and read it immediatelly. It might be the process of write haven't finished.How can cassandra guarantee what I read is the latest result I just wrote?

Comment: That is *your* decision, not Cassandra's. If you want to guarantee it, make sure your write and read happen at the appropriate consistency level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra has tuneable consistency. It is up to you to decide how much consistency you need - always on cost of availability.

If your write was not acknowledged at all you have no guarantees at all, but you *may* get the data back.

You can force Cassandra using ConsistencyLevel.ALL to force all nodes holding that partition key to acknowledge your write *and* to force all nodes to send data while reading. This will be slow and you might be better of using a RDBMS.

A good middle way is ConsistencyLevel.QUROUM.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html